# AD-Joined Samba Share with Windows XACL Access Denied

Tags: active-directory, samba, file-permissions

### Overview

- I have a file server and domain controller both running Samba 4.15.9.
- The DC is the only one in the forest.
- The DC, file server, and a Windows 10 client are joined to the same domain.
- On the file server, I have set up ADS security, AD idmap, and Windows ACL shares following the Samba wiki ([Domain Join](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member), [AD idmap](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Idmap_config_ad), [Windows ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs)).
- I have verified that all relevant domain users and groups can be enumerated on the file server.
- I am able to connect to and browse shares as a member of the owning group (`Unix Admins`), but not as a member of `Domain Users`; to which the ACL should allow access.

### Domain

- Two relevant groups exist in the domain; `Unix Admins` and `Domain Users`, both of which have `gidNumber` set to unique values within the idmap range.
- Two relevant users exist in the domain; `Admin` and `User`, both of which have `uidNumber` set to unique values within the idmap range. Both users are members of `Domain Users`.

  - `Admin` is a member of `Unix Admins`.

### File Server

- The Samba configuration on the file server is as follows (domain names changed):

  ```
  [global]
     security = ADS
     workgroup = WORKGROUP
     realm = REALM.WORKGROUP.COM
     server string = %h

     log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

     max log size = 1000
     logging = file

     panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

     idmap config * : backend = tdb
     idmap config * : range = 3000 - 7999
     idmap config REALM.WORKGROUP.COM : backend = ad
     idmap config REALM.WORKGROUP.COM : unix_nss_info = yes
     idmap config REALM.WORKGROUP.COM : range = 10000 - 999999
     idmap config REALM.WORKGROUP.COM : schema_mode = rfc2307

     vfs objects = acl_xattr
     map acl inherit = yes

     template shell = /bin/bash
     template homedir = /shares/user/%U

     username map = /etc/samba/user.map    # Only map is Administrator -> root
     winbind use default domain = yes
     winbind enum users = yes
     winbind enum groups = yes

     server role = member server
     map to guest = never

     server min protocol = SMB2_10
     server smb encrypt = required

  [users$]
     path = /shares/user/
     read only = no
     acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes
     comment = User Shares

  [shared]
     path = /shares/shared/
     read only = no
     acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes
     comment = Shared Folders

  [service]
     path = /shares/service/
     read only = no
     acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes
     comment = Service Shares
  ```
- `Unix Admins` has been granted `SeDiskOperatorPrivilege` on the file server.
- The POSIX permissions of the shared directories are all 771, owned by `root:"unix admins"`.
- The Windows ACLs of the shared directory root (`/shares`) is set as follows:

  - Owner: Unix Admins
  - Allow: Unix Admins: Full Control: This folder, subfolders and files
  - Allow: CREATOR OWNER: Modify: Subfolders and files only
  - Allow: Domain Users: Read & execute: This folder, subfolders and files
  - Allow: SYSTEM: Full Control: This folder, subfolders and files
- The "Share Permissions" for all relevant shares allow "Full Access" to "Everyone".

### Issue

Based on the aforementioned ACL, I would expect the user `User` to be able to browse shares, as they are a member of `Domain Users`. Indeed, calculating effective access for `User` states that they have the expected permissions. However, trying to connect to the share as `User` yields a permission error.

### Workaround

Setting the POSIX permissions for the entirety of the `/shares` directory tree to `775` allows the user to access the share as expected, while `777` allows the user to write with an appropriate ACL.

This, however, strikes me as less than ideal, and [the wiki page I followed](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs) seems to show setting up a share for `Domain Users` with POSIX permissions set to `770`.